# GoogleMap onMyLocationReady

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

i can get my current location from `GoogleMap` object by:

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
final Location myLocation = mMap.getMyLocation();
```

Problem is that if i run this code, `myLocation` is null because mMap still didn't connect to location service.

Is there a listener that tells me when the map is connected to the location service? similar to FuseLocation:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                   .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                   .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                   .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                   .build();
```

Thanks!

Roy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In google play services 6.5 there is now a `onMapReady` callback that gets fired after you call `getMapAsync()`

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback.html#onMapReady(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap)

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map

also note that just because the map is ready does not mean you will have a location

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, but it does not answer my question. 'mMap.getMyLocation()' will return null if i will run it from `onMapReady()`. i can only ask for a location after some time (when the blue myLocation dot appears), i want to know if there is a listener for that blue dot

Comment: sorry I misunderstood you, there is a deprecated callback `setOnMyLocationChangeListener` that i believe still works unless they took it out. Its deprecated because they want you to use your own location client instead